# How to default an embedded document to null with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

Lets say I have a schema with an embedded document called preferences that contains multiple values. I'm trying to have mongoose default the embedded document to null

For example here's how I've defaulted fields to null for basic types like Strings and Dates in the past.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
name: {type: String, required: true},
preferences: {type: preferences, default: null}
});

var preferences: {
preference1: String,
preference2: String
}
```

How should I default the property preferences in the userSchema to be null on a new document's creation?

Answer (score 25):

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  preferences: {type : { preference1 : String, preference2 : String}, default : null}
});
```

Tested with:

```
User.create({name : "Aladin"})
User.create({name : "Aladin", preferences : {preference1 : "Wunderlampen", preference2 : "Teppich" }})
```